# Why is System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode giving namespace name doesn't exist in Visual C# 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, urlencode

I'm trying to encode a URL using the `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` method, why am I getting

> The type or namespace name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

error ?
I'm using Visual C# 2008, Express Edition.

The code I'm using is simplistic:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
namespace Lincr
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cmdShorten_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebRequest wrURL;
            Stream objStream;
            wrURL = WebRequest.Create("http://lin.cr?l=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtURL.Text) + "&mode=api&full=1");
            objStream = wrURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader objSReader = new StreamReader(objStream);
            textBox1.Text = objSReader.ReadToEnd().ToString();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to include a reference to `System.Web`. Right-click your project in the Solution Explorer and choose *Add Reference...* . If you take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx) you'll see it's contained in the `System.Web.dll` assembly, as far as I remember, this is not referenced by default in new projects.

Comment: doesn't "using System.web" add the reference automatically ?

Comment: Have you checked that it is referenced?

Comment: @Sathya: Adding `using` directives has nothing to do with references, it merely gives you the possibility to use types from that namspace in the code file without specifying the full type name (so you can write `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` instead of `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode`).

Comment: Why wouldn't System.[anything] be included by default for any project? Makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 29):

Just in case anyone stumbles across this, is running VS 2010 and cannot find System.Web in the available references...

Right click on the project and select Properties, if the Target Framework is set to ".Net Framework 4 Client" then change it to ".Net Framework 4".

But beware this will close, reopen  and rebuild your project (also if you have a web service references these will need to be refreshed)

Comment: +1 Thanks.  I don't normally use Express, so I was wondering why I couldn't find this reference.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was missing something obvious.

Comment: Spot on the vs restart thing!

Comment: For Visual Basic users, the Framework should be changed from the "Compile" tab, in "Advanced Compile Options", at the bottom of the "Compile" tab.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398202(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 5):

For people using .NET 4.0 or later, you can use [WebUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) which works with client profile (does not require System.Web assembly reference).

Comment: I am having to use .NET 4.0 for one project, and only HtmlEncode and HtmlDecode are available on WebUtility.  There is no UrlEncode on the full profile.

Answer (score 0):

1. click on project tab in menu
2. click on Add References
3. in References window click on Framework and check the System.Web